# How to view email in "Combined View" in 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: email, gmail, 5.0-lollipop

After updating my Nexus 5 to Lollipop, the Email app tells me that the Gmail app will now handle all emails.  However, I'm having trouble being able to view all email accounts at once in the gmail app.

In the old Email application, at the bottom of the list of email accounts was a "Combined View" option.  When selected, it would display messages in the inbox of all linked accounts.  This option is missing in the list of accounts for the Gmail application.  How can I view emails from all inboxes in the Gmail app on 5.0?  If this is not possible, is there a way to get the old Email application back?

Comment: The Gmail app has never supported this in the past, so I would wager that there is no way to do what you're looking for (aside from using a different mail client).